# Using MVVM instead of MultiValueConverter in WPF XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I've been working with XAML for some time now, but when I started I didn't knew much about MVVM so I avoided it. So all the logic in my projects is written in .xaml.cs instead of ViewModel.cs. Now the project is big and I have to move some parts of it to MVVM per request and I have no clue how to do so or where to actually start.

about the problem:

I have two Entities. lets call them A and Secret.
A can have Secret. If A does have it I need to display Secret.Name and Secret.Description beside the A data.
They are binded together with: A.Secret == Secret.Id.

A data and B data can change independently and is received/changed over API calls, but A.Secret and Secret.Id bind will never change.

Secrets is just an array of SecretModel elements

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding A, ElementName=uc}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedA, ElementName=uc}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MaxHeight="300"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <TextBlock Text="ID:" TextAlignment="Right" />
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Id}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Type:" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Type}" />
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="Secret:" TextAlignment="Right" Visibility="{Binding Secret, Converter={StaticResource StringToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding Secret, Converter={StaticResource StringToVisibilityConverter}}">
                                        <TextBlock.Text>
                                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SecretIdToNameConverter}">
                                                <Binding Path="Secret"/>
                                                <Binding Path="Secrets" ElementName="uc"/>
                                            </MultiBinding>
                                        </TextBlock.Text>
                                        <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SecretIdToDescriptionConverter}">
                                                <Binding Path="Secret"/>
                                                <Binding Path="Secrets" ElementName="uc" />
                                            </MultiBinding>
                                        </TextBlock.ToolTip>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                    
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        
                    </ListBox>
```

Converters looks like this.

```
public class SecretIdToDescriptionConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values[0] != null && values[0] != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue && values[0] is string SecretId && values[1] != null && values[1] != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue && values[1] is SecretModel[] Secrets)
        {
            var tmp = Secrets.FirstOrDefault(secret => secret?.Id == SecretId);
            if (tmp != null)
                return tmp.Description;
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

If anyone could give me some help/pointers on how I should/could migrate from Converters of this type to MVVM or point me to some resource explaining it to me - that would be greatly appreciated.

The things that mostly boggles me:
How should I share/acces the data betwean .xaml.cs or .xaml and ViewModel.cs at this point?
How are calls made to retrieve/give such data?
Is it possible to create method that would return the corresponding SecretModel, so I could just use it after the call in .xaml?
like

```
<magic ItemsSource= getSecret(A.Secret) >
       <TextBlock Text = {Binding Name}/>
</magic>
```

Comment: I don't get it -- converters are not anti-mvvm

Comment: I don't get it either to be honest, but I have a task: "Remove SecretIdToNameConverter / SecretIdToDescriptionConverter: Use view model" and I'm trying to figure out how I should do so

Comment: You can bind the current entry out a collection using / notation.  By default the first is the current.  And it will fail So you don't actually need a converter at all for a xaml approach so long as the A Viewmodel has a public property which is a collection of Secrets. Binding Secrets/Name

Comment: In order to move the converter to the view model, you need to make sure the view model has access to the relevant properties. Then add a new property to the view model, which will hold the converted value. This new property actually replaces the return value of the converter. Bind the target directly to the new property. When either one of the relevant properties changes, update the new property.